# Q: How to extend the routing config in Rebus

Tags: rebus

I have a **rebus config project** which is shared for **many web api projects**

So basically, it looks like

*Web api 1* ==> *Shared Rebus Config*

*Web api 2* ==> *Shared Rebus Config*

*Web api 3* ==> *Shared Rebus Config*

**My question is, if I have some messages & handlers in Web api 3 project, how can I configure the routing for them?**

---

My current config:

```
var autofacContainerAdapter = new AutofacContainerAdapter(container);

return Configure
    .With(autofacContainerAdapter)
    .Serialization(s => s.UseNewtonsoftJson())
    .Routing(r =>
    {
        r.TypeBased()
            .MapAssemblyOf<ProjectA.MessageA>(EnvironmentVariables.ServiceBusQueueName)
            .MapAssemblyOf<ProjectB.MessageB>(EnvironmentVariables.ServiceBusQueueName);
    })
    .Sagas(s =>
    {
        s.StoreInSqlServer(EnvironmentVariables.ConnectionString, "Saga", "SagaIndex");
    })
    .Options(o =>
    {
        o.LogPipeline();
        o.EnableDataBus().StoreInBlobStorage(EnvironmentVariables.AzureStorageConnectionString, EnvironmentVariables.BlobStorageContainerName);
        o.EnableSagaAuditing().StoreInSqlServer(EnvironmentVariables.ConnectionString, "Snapshots");
    })
    .Logging(l =>
    {
        l.Use(new SentryLogFactory());
    })
    .Transport(t =>
    {
        t.UseAzureServiceBus(EnvironmentVariables.AzureServiceBusConnectionString, EnvironmentVariables.ServiceBusQueueName).AutomaticallyRenewPeekLock();
    })
    .Start();
```

Comment: What prevents you from configuring routing for your third web API the same way you did for the two first?

Comment: @mookid8000 I have some messages and handlers that only available for the third web api

Answer (score 1):

Well... as you have probably already found out, it is not possible to make additional calls to the `.Routing(r => r.TypeBased()....)` part. Therefore, I can see two fairly easy ways forward:

1: Simply pass additional parameters to your shared configuration method from the outside, e.g. something like this:

```
var additionalEndpointMappings = new Dictionary<Assembly, string>
{
    { typeof(Whatever).Assembly, "another-queue" }  
};
var bus = CreateBus("my-queue", additionalEndpointMappings);
```

which of course then needs to be handled appropriately in the `.Routing(...)` configuration callback.

2: Pull out all the common configurations into a new extension method. I almost always use this method myself, because I have found it to be easy to maintain.

First you create a new `RebusConfigurer` extension method in a shared lib somewhere:

```
// shared lib

public static class CustomRebusConfigEx
{
    public static RebusConfigurer AsServer(this RebusConfigurer configurer, string inputQueueName)
    {
        return configurer
            .Logging(...)
            .Transport(...))
            .Sagas(...)
            .Serialization(...)
            .Options(...);
    }    
}
```

and then you can call this by going

```
Configure.With(...)
    .AsServer("my-queue")
    .Start();
```

in your endpoints.

3: A combination of (1) and (2) which enables this:

```
Configure.With(...)
    .AsServer("my-queue")
    .StandardRouting(r => r.MapAssemblyOf<MessageType>("somewhere-else"))
    .Start();
```

which can end up avoiding repetitive code, still preserving a great deal of flexibility, and actually looking pretty neat :)

Comment: thanks a lot, I'll try both methods and get back to you

Comment: can you please provide an example of 1), I can't use assembly in `MapAssemblyOf<T>()` because it requires **generic** type